# How to download a new voice for say's function with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm searching a method to install different voices (2 to be exact) on the system preferences.
The voices are "Alex" for an english voice and "Thomas" for a french voice.

I've tried directly by console but didn't succeed, that's why I've turned to the AppleScript language, but I never used this language.

The code I've for the moment is

```
set osver to system version of (system info)
if osver is equal to "10.6.8" then
    display dialog ("Downloading voices is only available in OS X Lion and higher")
else
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal (pane id "com.apple.preference.speech")
    end tell

    try
        tell application "System Events"
            click radio button 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
            repeat until (exists pop up button of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences")
                delay 2
            end repeat
            delay 2
            click pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
            delay 2
            click menu item -1 of menu 1 of pop up button of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
            delay 2
        end tell
    on error
        display dialog ("An error happend")
    end try
end if
```

This program is opening the voice window but the display dialog appears every time whatever the index I put.

If you have another idea to download the voices, or if you can help me to understand what is not working, I will be grateful.

Comment: Which 'display dialog appears ever time'? The error?  Its working here for me on 10.7 in that the Customise... sheet is opened.  You just need to drill down into it and its table to click the appropriate checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, the display dialog on error appears...
Every time I modify this line
click menu item -1 of menu 1 of pop up button of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
I've the error message...

Comment: Try changing your error block to this `on error msg number num \n display dialog ("An error happend: '" & msg & "' #" & num) \n end try`  To see what's happening.

Comment: Also try addressing the menu item by name: e.g. `click menu item "Customize..."`

Comment: Ok, so I've modified the error block and I get this message with the menu "Customize..." or -1
"An error happend: 'System Events got an error: menu item "Customize..." of menu 1 of pop up button of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" doesn’t understand the “click” message.' #-1708"

Why it appears when I'm not asking anymore to click? (I've understand that my code stopped here, I don't ask him to no anything else after opening the customize, am I right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in 10.9:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "TTS" of pane id "com.apple.preference.speech"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1
        click
        click menu item "Customize..." of menu 1
    end tell
    delay 1
    repeat with r in UI element 1 of rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1
        if exists static text 1 of r then
            if {"Alex", "Thomas"} contains value of static text 1 of r then
                if value of checkbox 1 of r is 0 then click checkbox 1 of r
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    click button "OK" of sheet 1
end tell
```

It took multiple seconds to run the script though.

Comment: I just cc/cv your code and I get this message
System Events got an error: Can’t get sheet 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.

Comment: Try it again now. I edited the script to add a delay after the sheet is opened.

Comment: Ok, I had tried with adding a delay but it wasn't working, with your code is working, thank you very much.