# how do I install OS X TTS voices from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, speech

OS X Lion comes with some fantastic voices from Nuance. I would like to use them from my software, however, currently they require the user to manually go to System Preferences, Dictation and Speech, System Voice -> Customize, then download the voices from Apple. I would like to call something from Objective-C so that that voices that are missing (say Chinese voices) are automatically downloaded in the background. How can this be done?

Incidentally, the available voices on the system can be found using

```
[NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices]
```

but all the possible voices (so far) can only be found in the Dictation and Speech dialog. Here is how it is done manually:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This may be helpful http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/01/08/synthesized-speech-from-text.html

Comment: Thanks but link is for iOS instead of OSX.

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt there is any reliable way to do this.

You should just point the user to a help page explaining the process (preferably a help page on apple's website if possible, since they'll keep it updated if the process changes).

You're going to need root access to do it, which is banned from App Store apps. And it almost certainly needs to tie into the software update process which is extremely complex, completely undocumented, and subject to change at any time.

Alternatively, contact nuance for a license to distribute the voices yourself. They are all for sale. Maybe you can even get a discounted price if you only install if on macs where the user can get them for free.

Comment: I feel slightly sad that the no answer is the only answer. Can AppStore apps ask for root access? Or run an installer that does so? I wonder if there is a scripting way to do it? Maybe listen to the packets and see how the voices are being brought down and replicate?

Comment: The install prompt, does it come from a downloaded installer? Or from the Dictation and Speech applet? Perhaps all it does is lookup and online index and then download the installer and run it. May already ask for root access automatically.

Comment: "2.27 Apps that request escalation to root privileges or use setuid attributes will be rejected" — so no, you can't do it from an App Store app.

Comment: The install prompt is part of the pkg, run `man pkgutil` and also see `apropos pkg` for other pkg related command line utilities, that you could use, if you're willing to require root access and risk violating copyright by downloading the file directly (I'm not a lawyer. I think this would be a legal grey area).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586758/1861897) AppleScript to programmatically install TTS Voice, but MacOS is coming with all voices!

But Not all are showed in "Dictation & Speech->System Voice".

The reason is that they are very simple(compact) version and MacOS show only the full version of instaled Voice(s) like:"Alex".

**Examples:**

*My Configuration:*
[image]

You can see that I have only english voices but the next example work perfectly with spanish text.

*Swift example:*

```
var voice:NSSpeechSynthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer(voice: "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.diego")
voice.startSpeakingString("España y los españoles")
```

*Terminal example:*

```
say -v monica "En España a los españoles les encanta paella"
```

Comment: I think there must be regular and enhanced voices somehow.

Answer (score 0):

How to get the download list is a mystery... yet...

Using wireshark, it is possible to determine the voice location. Indeed a pkg is downloaded from Apple. Whether credentials, etc. are needed, is a separate issue.

[image]

Here are additional sample URLs:

/content/downloads/10/29/041-5265/kKRs5z32DcbrGdV4TZvY9hcqy8tcpkbX43/MLV_en_AU_karen.pkg

After download, could then run installer to install.

**Update.** I was able to download the pkg from Windows using http. Also, this other link

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/59/49/041-4469/WNshMBxxbxx5qXv27Mrvxm7yKcSRM75sVw/041-4469.English.dist

gives information about 041-4469 including the package name.

Comment: The problem is that URL can change at any time. The whole system of providing software updates can change at any time. Apple has a history of changing these things frequently. And if they learn people are relying on them behaving a certain way, then Apple is likely to implement encryption to make it extremely difficult to reverse engineer. They don't like it when app developers rely on behaviour that is not officially supported by Apple. It's their opinion that if your app works today, it should still work perfectly in 5 years when they have changed the platform significantly.